# SVG shake animation on hover

Tags: css, animation, svg

I am trying to make an svg img shake with CSS keyframes when you hover over it.

This is the effect I am trying to achieve: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ7CQHXPG42J

There is some javascript that animates the same svg but it targets a parent div #ellipse, that moves from left to right whenn clicked on the hamburger icon. I don't see how it could interfere, but I've added it just to make sure.

I have added the relevant code below. For the full code please see the website.

```js
// Other unrelated(!?) animations on #ellipse //

function moveEllipseRight() {
  ellipse.animate([
    // keyframes
    {
      transform: 'translateX(0px)'
    },
    {
      transform: 'translateX(' + width + 'px)'
    }
  ], {
    // timing options
    duration: 500,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: 'ease-in-out',
    fill: 'forwards'
  });
}

function moveEllipseLeft() {
  ellipse.animate([
    // keyframes
    {
      transform: 'translateX(' + width + 'px)'
    },
    {
      transform: 'translateX(0px)'
    }
  ], {
    // timing options
    duration: 500,
    iterations: 1,
    easing: 'ease-in-out',
    fill: 'forwards'
  });
}
```

```css
#ellipse {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  z-index: -99;
  animation: 3s linear 0s slide 1;
  left: -200px;
}

img.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 0px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(3px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translate(1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-1px, 2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translate(-3px, 1px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: translate(3px, 1px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(-1px, -1px) rotate(1deg);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translate(1px, 2px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, -2px) rotate(-1deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ellipse">
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-yqttzktPkDY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABGU/z6CVGRmY-C8/photo.jpg?sz=328" alt="ellipse" class="shake" width="400" height="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it is working fine, Could be because of something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `#ellipse` style.

```
#ellipse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: -99; /* remove this, it is not doing anything useful. */ 
    animation: 3s linear 0s slide 1;
    left: -200px;
}
```

---

the issue was, hover was not getting triggered at all, as it was behind `container` element due to negative `z-index`. This negative z index is not useful at all, unless you are planning to put text above the image, which I do not see in your site.

Comment: Hi Prajwal, thank you! Thas does seem to be the issue! I put a z-index as I wanted the object to slide behind the text when it moves from left to right when you click on the navigation. The navigation is still on top so it still blocks the animation when the <header> is open as it is on top of #ellipse, but I can live with that.